# Export Glossary Content ( to other CMS and as PDF)

Tags: content-management-system, export, vote, glossary

How can I export a glossary (and its content) from Plone to another CMS?

How can website-users export glossary content? (e.g. as PDF-file)?

How can I implement a voting-mechanism in the glossary to enable users to vote whether glossary-terms should be published or not?

Thanks in advance and best regards!